# Join these two formulas so that it only gives me an excel result

Tags: google-sheets

doing a job on LaLiga santander (Spanish football), I'm creating a code to award the third place in the champions league. The two conditions are that they look for the fourth team with the most points, and if several coincide, that they look for the team with the best goal difference among them. This is the line of code for the first condition:

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(",";1;IF($D$43:$AQ$43=LARGE($D$43:$AQ$43;4);$D$3:$AQ$3;"")))
```

And this is the code for the second one:

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(",";1;IF(E44:AQ44=LARGE(E44:AQ44;4);$D$3:$AQ$3;"")))
```

I manage to get the results in two different cells, and I wonder if there is a way to combine both formulas in the same one, so that it first looks for the team with the fourth most points, and then between them the team with the best goal difference.

I attach an image with the table for help:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuzK4.png)

I have tried with the AND() function inside the IF() function and with IFS(), but I get nothing. The result should be "Atletico Madrid"

Comment: Use another `TEXTJOIN()` or `JOIN()` or `CONCAT()` to put multiple results into single cell.

Comment: neither ```AND()``` nor ```IFS()``` function do what you are asking for, google sheet and excel very much self-explain most of their basic functions like these, they even provide in-App notes, samples and descriptions, all you need to do is ```READ THOSE TEXT```, you will than understand a bit more of what these functions are for.

Comment: Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel have different feature sets and will most likely require a different answer each. The [google-sheets] tag description explicitly states _"Do NOT use with [excel]"_ and the [excel] tag description explicitly states _"Do NOT use with other spreadsheet software like [google-sheets]."_ Choose one platform and edit tags appropriately.